# не выводит изображения в pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixijs

Пишу простенькую игру на pixi.js

Для начала логика простая: нарисуй поле, а на поле нарисуй элемент

```
var app = new PIXI.Application(800, 600, {backgroundColor : 0x1099bb});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

var bunny = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('1ZombieSpriteSheet.png')

bunny.anchor.set(0.5);

bunny.x = app.renderer.width / 2;
bunny.y = app.renderer.height / 2;

app.stage.addChild(bunny);
```

вроде все просто и должно все выводить но нет. При запуске игры в браузере пишет сообщение

```
Access to Image at 'file:///C:/RS-School/tibmt-front-end-course/game/1ZombieSpriteSheet.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

В чем дело?

Comment: На локальной машине делаете?

Comment: Нет, просто запускаю ее в браузере

Comment: Все сделал, спасибо Даниил

Comment: Дело в политике " CORS ", она запрещает обращение к этому файлу, ибо думает, что кто-то пытается украсть файлы.